# A Telegram bot that provides a user's username when given the user ID, and vice versa

Tags: telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I want to make a telegram bot using the PyTelegramBotAPI (telebot) library.
It should give the user's username when you type "/lk " and the user's id when you type "/lk <@username>", however, I dont really know how to do that.
Can someone help me please?
Many thanks.

I tried many versions of the code, modified everything when it didn't work, but it still doesn't work.